# Stop multiple RDS instances using AWS CLI command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have been trying to stop multiple instances of RDS using a single command line but it does not seem to work.

Currently I can only make it work with one instance at a time with a command like this:

`aws rds stop-db-instance --db-instance-identifier test-instance1 --region ap-southeast-1 --profile dev`

However I would like to stop multiple RDS and this does not seem to work:

`aws rds stop-db-instance --db-instance-identifier test-instance1 test-instance2 testinstance3 --region ap-southeast-1 --profile dev`

Any idea or suggestion on how I can make this work?

If it is not possible I will probably create a CRON job instead using Lambda.

Comment: Why are you using Lambda to run an awscli command, and why is it problematic for you to have to stop RDS instances one by one?

Comment: @jarmod I am currently using AWS CLI via CMD and not Lambda. Since I have to start the all RDS instances in the morning and stop them after working hours, it is not convenient to stop them one by one via AWS Console or run many cli commands when I have 30 RDS instances to start/stop. I am looking for a faster way, that is why

Comment: This would be a simple task for a scheduled Lambda. It could dynamically enumerate the RDS instances with certain tags (preferable to using a static list of RDS instance identifiers imo) and then stop them. The StopDBInstance API doesn't support multiple DBs in a single call so no SDK (or the awscli) offers this feature. But that doesn't mean it's difficult to stop multiple RDS instances. Just invoke the API multiple times, once per database. And, here's [an article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/schedule-amazon-rds-stop-and-start-using-aws-lambda/) explaining how to do exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly you can't do this. But you can write a simple bash **for loop**:

```
ids=(test-instance1 test-instance2 test-instance3)

for id in ${ids[@]}; 
do
    echo "Stopping: ${id}" 
    aws rds stop-db-instance --db-instance-identifier ${id} --region ap-southeast-1 --profile dev
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If writing a shell script that calls `aws rds stop-db-instance` multiple times, once per RDS instance, is problematic for you somehow, then consider doing this via a scheduled Lambda (think of it like crontab).

See [Schedule Amazon RDS stop and start using AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/schedule-amazon-rds-stop-and-start-using-aws-lambda/), which:

> presents a solution using AWS Lambda and Amazon EventBridge that allows you to schedule a Lambda function to stop and start the idle databases with specific tags to save on compute costs.